Robot Framework String Library, Convert To Title Case
While understanding string library of Robot framework, I run the following code.
   ${str}=  Convert To Title Case  distance is 1 km. km! km? km$ km% km5 km& kmC  exclude=is,km.

and got the output
   Distance is 1 km. km! km? km$ km% km5 km& kmC

I was expecting the code will exclude km. only but it exclude any word that starts with km.
Anyone please explain this behaviour for me?
tried
${str}=  Convert To Title Case  distance is 1 km. km! km? km$ km% km5 km& kmC  exclude=is,km.
Output
Distance is 1 km. km! km? km$ km% km5 km& kmC
expecting
Distance is 1 km. Km! Km? Km$ Km% Km5 Km& KmC

Looking at the source code of the keyword, that happens because each exclude token is treated as a regular expression.
And in regexp the dot . has a special meaning - it is treated as "any character". Effectively it caches itself, the exclamation mark, etc in your sentence.
You may try escaping the dot, so for regexp that would mean "literally a dot char":
   ${str}=  Convert To Title Case  distance is 1 km. km! km? km$ km% km5 km& kmC  exclude=is,km\.


By the way, "kmC" will never be capitalized - the keyword's doc say: Exclude words that are not all lower case. This preserves, for example, "OK" and "iPhone".
